# computer reboots randomly, can't find ssd

Tags: ssd, reboot

My comp's been restarting at random times, and when it comes back the SSD drive can't be found by the BIOS and it doesn't boot. Powering down and starting up again fixes it 90% of the time, with a second reboot occasionally required.

Does not seem to be heat related; it's never happened with me actually on the computer. It has happened while acting as the squeezebox server, however.

It's a Sandy-Bridge i7 arch if that helps.

To add: I've also run Windows Memtest and it came back with no issues.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be affected by the [Cougar Point chipset flaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandy_Bridge#Cougar_Point_chipset_flaw), would you?

Comment: Nope, this is an Asus Z68 board

Comment: Perhaps a lack of (clean) power?  Have you run any diagnostics against the drive itself?  Any related system log entries?

Comment: No diagnostics against the actual drive, that's next. System and Event logs have nothing but the kernel power signal indicating a reboot. Nothing in Applications or System logs prior to the event to clue me in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a driver issue. Updating mobo and SSD drivers to the latest resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happening with an SSD and when I went into the BIOS and added an extra delay before recognizing devices, it failed the boot less frequently. Not the best solution, but it worked.